# how am I notified when someone has responded on meta.english.stackexchange.com

Tags: support

Is my meta.english.stackexchange.com site related to my english.stackexchange.com site?

I've had responses on meta.english.stackexchange.com but its not showing up at all (I do not know why someone had replied at all!)

Answer (score 4):

The only response I see to you here is [this answer](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/version-control-questions-on-topic), which *does* show up in your inbox (available by clicking the little StackExchange link at the top-left of the page).

Are there others you expect to see?